# Angular 13 throw specific error message from backend

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I have an application (back+front). I'm a newbie in angular and frontend, and I want to know how to get the specific message of error from the backend

When I create a person and I write his email as an invalid email in the backend I get this:
[image]

In my angular app i have errorHandler:

```
errorHandler(error:any) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      errorMessage = Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message};
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

which i catch in my  create method:

```
create(user:User): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiURL + 'api/user/', JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      )
  }
```

I connected toastr to display some message if the operation is successfull or not:

```
  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.messageService.create(this.form.value).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.toastr.success("Created successfully!");
      console.log('Post created successfully!');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('messages').then(r => console.log(r));
    },
      (error)=>{
      void this.toastr.error(error.messageType,"We have an error! Something went wrong")
      })
  }
```

[image]

But I get only static message that something is wrong, and I need to get the specific message from my backend(if the username is already taken, or the email is invalid)

When i write error  with toastr:

```
(error)=>{
      void this.toastr.error(error,"We have an error! Something went wrong")
      })
```

I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's always safer to pass a closure instead of function reference where `this` is involved:

```
catchError(err => this.errorHandler(err))
```

Secondly, `throwError()` must be given an error factory and not a constant value, like:

```
throwError(() => errorMessage);
```

Thirdly, I'm not sure what exactly you expect to see, but you do nothing with `error` in your `submit()` call, did you mean something like this?

```
error => this.toastr.error(error.messageType, `We have an error: ${error}`)
```

Comment: Yeah , when i write  error.messageType or error.message i get nothing , but when i write just error i have some message ( i editted my post with the screen of it)

Comment: Is it not what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one interceptor? In my case, one of the interceptors was **re-throwing the error.message instead of the error**, which led to other interceptors only getting the message rather than the whole object.

Re-throwing error as it was:

`return throwError(() => new Error(err.message));`

How it should be so other interceptors can access the error object:

`return throwError(() => err);`

**Remember:**
Interceptors work as middleware. **Order matters**.

- Requests go from index **0 to N**.
- Responses go from index **N back to 0**.

Angular applies interceptors in the order you provide them.